# man page: how to see progress through file (MacOS)

Tags: man

When viewing a man page, is there a way to see visually where you are in the file?  Typing `=` shows the line numbers currently in view, but does not show how many lines are in the file.  I'm not looking for a clickable scrollbar, but just a visual indicator of how close I am to the beginning or end of the man page.

Comment: What do you see with `=`? Don't you see something like `lines 3-24/1000 byte 63/3893 2%`?

Comment: I have edited the question to focus specifically on man pages.  Viewing a regular text document, I do see the percentage as you suggest.  Viewing a man page, I do not.

Comment: OK, please also update your title since "scrollbar thumb" doesn't really mean anything (does it?) and make sure to tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what pager you are using.

Comment: I'm willing to use a different pager, so far I've used the default pager `less`.  That's why my original question (before editing) asked about `less`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marcus Muller is correct that `less` needs to know the file size before it can give a percentage location indicator.  Other than pre-determining the file size, another method is to force `less` to read all the input at startup.  One way to do this is to ask `less` to go to end-of-file, then go to start-of-file.

In `bash`:

```
$ export PAGER='less +G1G -P"%Pb\%"'
$ man man
MAN(1)                  FreeBSD General Commands Manual                 MAN(1)

NAME
     man – display online manual documentation pages

SYNOPSIS
[ ... ]
             behavior.  Overrides the MACHINE_ARCH and MACHINE environment
30%
```

My testing shows this isn't a perfect solution, but it's close, so perhaps someone more knowledgeable than I can refine it further.

Answer (score 1):

So, by default that's impossible, `less` needs to know how long the input is before it calculates how far you're in. But: `less` has an option `--file-size`, which counts the length of the file as it's loaded. It doesn't do that by default because maybe there's text files for which that reading takes a long time.

Well, `man` pages typically don't belong in that category. For some reason, `man` still calls `less` without `--file-size`.

No big deal,

```bash
export MANPAGER="less --file-size"
```

solves that problem :)

Comment: With `export MANPAGER="less --file-size"` I get `There is no file-size option`.

Comment: @Rich006 oh! `less --version` says what?

Comment: `less --version` says `less 581.2 (POSIX regular expressions)`

Comment: @Rich006 interesting! my 590 has that, so that must *really* be a rather new development. In that case, go for Jim's answer. Should work.